# React-Native-Firebase Crashlytics not tracking, events working IOS

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

Using react-native-firebase version 5.5.5 in my react-native version 0.59.9 project.

Recently the IOS crashlytics have stopped tracking, and the latest version is not in the crashlytics selection screen, however the events are still being tracked on ios and the Android version is still having it's crashlytics populating.

I've tried updating the react-native-firebase package to version 7+ with no effect, I've also followed the v6 migration documentation and still cannot get crashlytics to populate the newest version of the ios app. I've tried both local testing on a real device as well as testflight release. I'm able to use the package to force crashes and within the log I see it says it sent the report to crashlytics, I can also see the crash being reported in the firebase stream view, but never populates to crashlytics. I've downloaded the dsym files from the appstore and uploaded them via command line, however there are no warnings about missing dsym files for the newest versions.

This is what my podfile looks like

```
pod 'Stripe', '~> 14.0.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 6.3.0'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.2'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport', '~> 3.14.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.26.0'

pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

pod 'tipsi-stripe', :path => '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe'
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
```

I also still have the run script command `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"`

I have enabled crashlytics collection at the root of the app with `firebase.crashlytics().enableCrashlyticsCollection();`

Gone through a lot of the solutions suggested on react-native-firebase issues threads but none seem to help.